# Simplest way to retrieve a Job results?

Tags: python, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

I have a python program launching a batch job. The job outputs a json file, I'd like to know what is the easiest way to get this result back to the python program that launched it.

So far I thought of these solutions:

- Upload the json file to S3 (pretty heavy)
- Display it in the pod logs then read the logs from the python program (pretty hacky/dirty)
- Mount a PVC, launch a second pod with the same PVC, and create a shared disk between this pod and the job (pretty overkill)

The json file is pretty lightweight. Isn't there a solution to do something like adding some metadata to the pod when the job completes? The python program can then just poll those metadata.

Comment: Allow outbound traffic to the batch job and save the JSON to a NoSQL database like DynamoDB or MongoDB?

Comment: That's also pretty heavy imo, I would like my initial python program to do that job instead of the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way not involving any other databases/pods is to run the first pod as an init container, mount a volume that is shared in both containers and use the JSON file in the next python program. (Also, this approach does not need a persistent volume, just a shared one), see this example:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Also, depending on the complexity of these jobs, would recommend taking a look at Argo workflows or any dag-related job schedulers.